# Android 13 Tiramisu - Access files in Download Folder - EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-13, android-tiramisu

I have an app that downloads some mp3 files into some folder such as /storage/emulated/0/myFolder1/myFolder2/file.mp3

I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Before Android 13, after requesting permission it works, but on Android 13, even permission dialog does not show up and I couldn't download the file.

To make Android 13 compatible with minimum effort, I moved the path into Download folder, such as /storage/emulated/0/Download/myFolder2/file.mp3

That way I was able to download the file, but when I try to read it using

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FullAddress); 
// full address is /storage/emulated/0/Download/myFolder2/file.mp3
```

That code throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/myFolder2/file.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

How can I properly read the file that I downloaded on Android 13?

I don't want to use internal app storage, because those files can be replaced from PC or any other way, they must be accessible.

Comment: Who downloaded the file? Your app? How?

Comment: Use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to read the file.

Comment: My app has downloaded, as I wrote, to that directory I can manually upload files as well. Files are there, just I cannot access them properly @blackapps

Comment: It makes no sense to say that your app was able to create a file which then later could not be read.

Comment: I have no idea why you are telling that you can upload files.

Comment: Strange, but it is how it is @blackapps. I was able to download, maybe system lets me because of it is "Download" folder.

Comment: I can upload files from PC to that folder in Download as well. Not only my app will download, maybe I may be able to upload files to the phone using PC. Can we focus on how can I access to those files?

Comment: Your app can read files it created itself. Not files created by other apps.

Comment: Repeat: `Use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to read the file.`. Do it and report.

Comment: @blackapps your answer is irrelevant. File exists (I can see it in file manager) and I cannot skip that if I cannot read, I'm looking for a way to access to the file on Android 13, because on lower versions of Android that already works by asking READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: You can try this: [Granular Media Permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)

Comment: @ayushimaheshwari those are for certain media types, how can I apply to my situation?

Comment: Add this permission [READ_MEDIA_AUDIO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_AUDIO) in manifest and in permission dialog

Comment: Adding asking explicitly MEDIA_READ_AUDIO solved the access denied problem @ayushimaheshwari thanks. I realized now another problem, that if the folder is empty, I can download files to the folder and I can have access. Later when I copy new version of the files from somewhere to this directory and overwrite the files, I can't re-download and overwrite from my app. Looks like I don't have write permission anymore because my app is not the creator of that. How can I fix this?